# Hosting own js and related libraries in shared location

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, tomcat, cdn

I've a range of web applications that all have their own lib folder which contain jQuery, css, AngularJS etc...

The required libraries are imported at beginning of every page that requires their use. Each app is importing the required libraries from its own lib folder.

I plan created a new static project "SHARED-LIBS" which will contain all libraries in use. Each project will then import the required library from this shared folder instead of its own lib folders. The shared folder will be hosted on tomcat within webapps folder so other projects can reference it. I cannot use a public CDN so trying to create my own extremely stripped down version. The amount of requests this "SHARED-LIBS" will server is quite low so don't need to be concerned with scaling. Is this a good approach ? Is there anything else I should consider ?

Comment: The JavaScript libraries you show are extremly small. Do you think it is worth the effort? You can also import them using npm, bower and such.

Comment: @Stefan library size is not the issue. If all libraries are in same folder then updates to library version occurs in one place, it's easy to see what libraries are in use, creation of new projects is simpler as do not have to create another lib folder that project. Agree, bower could solve this issue also but my exp of bower is that when adding dependency it tends to also include other redundant dependencies, increasing the complexity of the project.